# background-image not showing on mobile but showing on desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

l got a landing page up and running here compare.comxa.com..when l try to view on my android device only the form shows,the background image is no where to be found. please can you help.
this is the code

```css
body {
    height:100%;
    background: url("http://bit.ly/1MOnMVB") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
#mc_embed_signup {
    background:#fff;
    clear:left;
    font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    position:absolute;
    top:85px;
    left:35px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
h2 {
    color:orange;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
h5 {
    color:#483D8B;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>black friday deals</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="author" content="ataga austin">
  <meta name="keywords" contents="black friday,deals,black firday deals,black friday deal comapre">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
  <link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class=" col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                        
                        <div id="mc_embed_signup">
                            <form action="//comxa.us12.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=3380c08f529e58f0eadc50f43&amp;id=ab83c00a63" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
                                <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                                    <h2>Best Black Friday Deals</h2>
                                    <h5>Compare Prices Across Your Favourite Stores</h5>
                                    <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
                                    <div class="mc-field-group">
                                        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
                                        </label>
                                        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder=" something@some.com">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mc-field-group">
                                        <label for="mce-FNAME">Name </label>
                                        <input type="text" value="" name="NAME" class="" id="mce-NAME" placeholder=" smith davis">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mc-field-group">
                                        <label for="mce-PRODUCT">PRODUCT </label>
                                        <input type="text" value="" name="PRODUCT" class="" id="mce-PRODUCT" placeholder="apple tv" >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mc-field-group">
                                        <label for="mce-LNAME">FAVORITE STORE </label>
                                        <input type="text" value="" name="STORE" class="" id="mce-STORE" placeholder=" amazon">
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                                        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none">   </div>
                                        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none">          </div>
                                    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
                                    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_3380c08f529e58f0eadc50f43_ab83c00a63" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                                    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="btn btn-success"></div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    <script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script>
                    <script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='PRODUCT';ftypes[2]='text';fnames[3]='STORE';ftypes['3']='text';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
                    <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you add some screenshots

Comment: Try cleaning your code a little bit and make a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to load the background image from a protected ftp server. That works only in the following format `ftp://user:password@server.tld`
BUT that's clearly not recommended (password in cleartext!)

So rather than doing something stupid as that move the file to the right directory on the web server and just reference it like this: `background-image: url(bkg1.jpeg);`

Comment: your suggestion worked and its displays in mobile now but the image does not cover the whole page like it does on desktop..please what can l do and could you tell me how my password is in clear text..thanks

Comment: add the following style to the document: `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Answer (score 1):

Background image is not loading because it can't get access to to your account where you have your image Just change image url and it will work

```
background: url("http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/HD-Wallpapers1_Q75eDHE.jpeg") no-repeat center center fixed;
```